# QTabBar, remove signal tabMoved(from, to) from function moveTab(from, to)

Tags: qt

As I am connecting a QListWidget to a QTabBar, I see that everytime I drag&drop a tab the signal tabMoved is triggered. This works perfectly.

It seems that even when I execute the function moveTab(from, to), the same signal is triggered. Is it possible to set the function moveTab not to trigger the signal tabMoved(from, to)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that will do,

```
myTabBar.blocksignals(true);
myTabBar.moveTab(from, to);
myTabBar.blocksignals(false);
```

Comment: You can also use `QSignalBlocker` for this, to leverage RAII.